# Splitting out a single field into multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:
*id, type, date, changelog*.

The *changelog* field has 10 useful pieces of information I would like to split out into their own fields.  both new and old: name, month, year, zipcode, status

So I would like to create a table with the following fields:
*id, type, date, old_name, new_name, old_month, new_month, old_year, new_year, old_zipcode, new_zipcode, old_status, new_status*.

When all 5 pieces of information exist it is easy but when some are missing I can’t get it to work.  Any help is appreciated.

a typical changelog field doesn't have all of these pieces of information, just what is being updated.

for example:

```
id   type    date      changelog
101  upd     1/1/2019  ---!hash:ActiveSupport
                       name:
                       - Adam
                       - Chris
                       month:
                       - 7
                       - 12
                       status:
                       - 1
                       - 3
```

Which would translate to:

```
id  type  date    old_name  new_name  old_month  new_month  old_year  new_year  old_zipcode  new_zipcode  old_status  new_status
101 upd   1/1/19  Adam      Chris     7          12                                                       1           3
```

Comment: i would suggest that you change your table in your database if possible. having all that information in one column spits in the face of relational database concepts. not the answer you are looking for but the way that column stores data is definitely not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution *(it assumes you can already parse out the values when you know they are present)*, but it addresses how to handle when those values are missing:

```
INSERT INTO tableV2 (id, type, date, old_name, new_name, and so on....)
SELECT id, type, date
, CASE WHEN INSTR(changelog, 'name:') = 0 THEN NULL 
  ELSE (parse the value out here)
  END AS old_name
, CASE WHEN INSTR(changelog, 'name:') = 0 THEN NULL 
  ELSE (parse the value out here)
  END AS new_name
, and so on....
FROM tableV1
;
```

The parsing, while not trivial, probably won't be too difficult other than the tediousness of it. You'll need to take the found "tag" location, find the 3 newlines following it (first for the tag, latter for each value), and then use those along with other [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) such as SUBSTR, LEFT... and maybe some CHAR_LENGTH(tag string) like `CHAR_LENGTH('name:')` to make the parsing repeatable for each tag with minor modification.